# List of images in 3 sizes

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images. They are in 3 sizes: Large, Medium and Small. Large is 3 times larger than Small (+ a little for spacing), Medium is 2 times the size of Small (+ a little for spacing). In this example Large is 160x160 pixels, Medium is 105x105 pixels and Small is 50x50 pixels.

I want all the Large to be shown first, then all Medium and then all Small. But I want the list to fill all the screen, meaning, there should not be empty spaces anywhere (except after the last image).

So I want this:
[image]

But if I just try with simply this code ([code also in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cntve6wf/2/)):

```html
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
```

Then I just get this result:
[image]

Sooo, how should I write the html/css to get the result that I want?

Note: I'm looking for a solution that is independent of screen width.

Comment: If you want you can use Flexbox or Grid Layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display grid can solve this in a beautiful way:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 55px);
    grid-auto-rows: 55px;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.big {
    grid-column: span 3;
    grid-row: span 3;
}

.mid {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="big" src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
<img class="big" src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
<img class="mid" src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
<img class="mid" src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is answered very easily with `floats`. By floating all the images left, you'll achieve your desired appearance.

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07be2rfj/).

### Code

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">

</body>
</html>
```

### Result

[image: EricC CSS]

Comment: One problem with this. I cannot add image in a comment, but if you make the width the jsfiddle output smaller, then you will see unwanted spaces.

Comment: This happen when the width can contain two blue images and one green...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `float:left` and putting the images in a container to make them stack properly:

```css
.container {
  width: 605px;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ywppzsf93/list-item-large.png" height="160" width="160">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/lsk5n3fhj/list-item-medium.png" height="105" width="105">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
  <img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/bv94u105z/list-item-small.png" height="50" width="50">
</div>
```

Comment: This has fixed width. I should have specified this, but I was looking for a more automatical adaptable solution independent of screen width.